# How to access HLS video transport segments (.ts) from Android player?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, m3u8, http-live-streaming

We have an Android player that plays an m3u8 stream. This m3u8 stream contains numerous transport segments of video that are played sequentially. Usually the player buffers a few transport segments.

If the user clicks a button, I would like to store the existing buffer of transport segments in an array (or other data structure) and immediately merge them to be an mp4. So, if the buffer has:

chunk123.ts
chunk124.ts
chunk125.ts

I would like to merge them to be a chunks.mp4

The second part of the task - the merging is something I am acquainted with. However, I am not sure how I can retrieve the transport segments in the video player buffer on Android (the video player handles the download). I supposed one would need an open source video player for this? What part of the code would I need to modify to make it accessible from within my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html). It handle m3u8 stream and persisten caching. You can easily add your custom logic because app is notified every time a chunck (ts file) is downloaded by the class [ChunkSampleSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/hls/HlsChunkSource.java).